# Using jQuery, filter textbox collection by text value

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I thought I could do the following:

```
var tb = JqueryCollectionOfTextboxes.filter(‘[value=“‘ + myValue + ‘"]’);
```

I also tried using `:compare` with no success.

But neither worked.

I know I can use `$.each` and iterate through `JqueryCollectionOfTextboxes`, comparing the value of each with "myValue", but it seems less elegant to do so.

So text cannot be used as a selector for a textbox?

David

Comment: Do you really have curly quotes in the code, or is that a copying error?

Comment: The code shown would be producing a syntax error visible in the browser's development console.  (It also serves as an example of why a word processor is not an IDE.)

Comment: Typed it on an ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute selectors filter by the attribute in the HTML, so this is checking what's in the `value="..."` attribute, not the value property that contains the user input. For that, you should use a callback function that tests the property.

```
var tb = JqueryCollectionOfTextboxes.filter((i, el) => el.value == myValue);
```